# Getting field value dynamically while using describefieldresult

Tags: apex, sobject, xml

What I have to do is to get all fields of an sObject and converting it into xml runtime. I have all the fields. And I get field name and field label in xml tag. What I want is field value instead of label. I search a lot but couldn't find any good help.Here is my code.

```
public class XmlBuilderC{
    String strAcId = '001280000033UsO';
    String objNameAccount = 'Account';
    String strContactId = '00328000001iIvs';
    String objNameContact = 'Contact';
    String xml;
    XmlStreamWriter w = new XmlStreamWriter();
    sObject sObjectAccount = [select id, name from account where id=:strAcId];
    SObject sObjectContact = [select id from contact where id=:strContactId];
    public Map <String, Schema.SObjectType> schemaMap = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();

    //sObject objsObjectAccount = objAccount;

    public XmlBuilderC(){                   
        printXml(objNameAccount); 
        printXml(objNameContact);                       
    }

    public void printXml(String sObjectName){
        Map <String, Schema.SObjectField> fieldMap = schemaMap.get(sObjectName).getDescribe().fields.getMap();
        w.writeStartDocument('utf-8','1.0');
        w.writeStartDocument(null,'<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/ xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">');
        for(Schema.SObjectField sfield : fieldMap.Values())
        {
            schema.describefieldresult dfield = sfield.getDescribe();                        
            System.debug('dfield.getLocalName(): '+dfield.getLocalName());
            w.writeStartElement(null,sObjectName,null);
            w.writeStartElement(sObjectName,dfield.getname(),sObjectName);
            w.writeCharacters(dfield.getLabel()); //***Here.***
            w.writeEndElement();
            w.writeEndDocument();
        }

        System.debug('End of printXml()');
    }

    public String getXml(){
        System.debug('inside getXml');
        xml = w.getXmlString();
        System.debug('xml: '+w.getXmlString());
        w.close();
        System.debug('XmlStreamWriter closed');
        return xml;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the values, you will need to perform a [dynamic SOQL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dynamic_soql.htm) query where you make sure that you include all the fields in the query by building the SOQL string from your describe data. You can then use [SObject.get(SObjectField)](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm#apex_System_SObject_get_2) for each of the `SObjectField` values on the query result.

Here is an example of dynamic SOQL that queries all the fields:

```
Id id = '001i000000UBpmI';
DescribeSObjectResult d = Account.SObjectType.getDescribe();
List<String> fields = new List<String>(d.fields.getMap().keySet());
String soql = 'select ' + String.join(fields, ', ') + ' from Account where Id = :id';
SObject sob = Database.query(soql);
System.debug(sob.get(Account.Name));
...
```

Comment: Hi, I am new in Salesforce so please allow me to ask a dumb question. Is there any way we can cast describefieldresult into sObject?

Comment: No. The describe call returns information about the structure of an SObject (table); it does not return data from any row of the SObject. To look at data from a row you need to tie down which row by e.g. the "where" clause of SOQL.

Comment: You saved me. :)